# C#: need to get all 'SampleData' for which "SampleDataConfig" config = Client

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get all 'SampleData' for which "SampleDataConfig" config = Client.

Below query give me `List<IEnumerable<SampleDataConfig>>` rather than `List<SampleData>`.

`var X = data.Select(s => s.SampleDataConfig.Where(p => p.Config == "Client")).ToList();`

What wrong here,

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<SampleData> data = new List<SampleData>
        {
            new SampleData { Name = "A1", SampleDataConfig = new List<SampleDataConfig> { new SampleDataConfig { Name = "Belong", Config = "Client" }, new SampleDataConfig { Name = "Belong", Config = "Server" } } },
            new SampleData { Name = "A2", SampleDataConfig = new List<SampleDataConfig> { new SampleDataConfig { Name = "Belong", Config = "Server" } } }
        };

        var X = data.Select(s => s.SampleDataConfig.Where(p => p.Config == "Client")).ToList();

        foreach(var x in X)
        {
            x.
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class SampleData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SampleDataConfig> SampleDataConfig { get; set; } = new List<SampleDataConfig>();
}

public class SampleDataConfig
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Config { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It will return SampleData where there are multiple values (one value is of client and another is server )of SampleDataConfig,  is that ok?

Comment: Thanks, it should return only 1 row of `SampleData` for above sample data, no matter for `SampleDataConfig`

Comment: Check my answer below. Its using linq query. I will try to make using LINQ lambda expression as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested and working

**Using LINQ query**

```
var X = (from sd in data
        from sdc in sd.SampleDataConfig
        where sdc.Config == "Client"
        select sd).ToList();
```

**Using LINQ Lambda**

```
var Y = data.Where(x => x.SampleDataConfig.Any(s=>s.Config == "Client")).ToList();
```